# Translating C# Delegates from 2005 Project to C# 2003

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2005, visual-studio-2003, backport

I’m trying to compile in VS2003 that *MouseTracking* project that was made in C# 2005. I’ve got it fixed up except for one line:

```
    proc = HookCallback;
```

This gives the error    `Method 'MouseTracking.MouseTracker.HookCallback(int, System.IntPtr, System.IntPtr)' referenced without parentheses`

If I add parantheses to HookCallback, I get    `No overload for method 'HookCallback' takes '0' arguments`

I have tried adding the function arguments as types, variable names, and both, but none seem to work.

Here are the relevant definitions:

```
    private LowLevelMouseProc proc;
    private delegate IntPtr LowLevelMouseProc (int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
    private          IntPtr HookCallback      (int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam) {…}
```

Any idea how to get this to compile? I’d really like to add and tweak a few things.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like it's using HookCallback as a delegate.  In C# 1 you have to create delegates using a delegate constructor, you can't just use the method name ([like you can in C# 2+](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173176%28VS.80%29.aspx)).

Take a look at the type of `proc`, and use that to create a new delegate, like so:

```
proc = new LowLevelMouseProc(HookCallBack);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that worked and makes sense. (I’m from C++, so I’ve done very little in C#).

Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

```
prot = new LowLevelMouseProc(HookCallBack);
```